# Permission rights on automatic directories inside /media

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, media

I got a `permission denied` when I am trying to `cd` inside a directory.

I could `chown` it for my user, however I'm wondering if the problem is elsewhere:

The directory in question is an automatic directory added inside `/media` when I plug my usb external drive. I have read that the points inside `/media` are automatically removed, so I doubt about the usefulness of my `chown`.

Is there a way to give access to the user to all the usb things I'm going to plug that will appear inside `/media` ?

**Edit**: I rebooted, with the drive unplugged, logged in, then plugged the drive, and then it appears ready to be mounted in PcManFM.

From what I have seen, when it's mounted, there's a point `/media/MyDrive_` owned by my user that has been created (`/media/MyDrive` without the trailing underscore is owned by root). It's when that point has been created, that the drive can no longer be accessed by another user.

So now it's no longer a real problem for me, since the other user was just optionnal in my setup. But it would be nice to know how to get over it when switching between users. Should I unmount external drives any time I log out ?

**Edit2**: I don't find the webpage, but I have read about a `storage` user group, can it be related to that ?

Comment: What are you using to handle your automounting? Your DE? A udev rule/helper?

Comment: I don't know. I'm gonna search since I don't know neither what is a DE or a udev rule.

Comment: What filesystem is on the drive?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this usb drive plugged has ntfs filesystem on it. It's all the data I brought with me quitting windows.

Comment: @jasonwryan DE = Desktop Environment ok. At first I was using Ubuntu Unity with Nautilus, but it's been two or three months I'm just using FluxBox with PcManFM. I didn't write any udev rule myself.

Comment: @jasonwryan I have just gone back on nautilus and ubuntu unity, right now just to test, but it didn't help. (nothing's changed).

Comment: I have edited the question. It seems that it is the mounting of the external drive by one user that excludes it to others.

Comment: If you want it available to all users, you will need an entry in your `/etc/fstab` with the `users` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because the partitions were already mounted by another user.

the solution is simply to unmount partition for the other user, then everything is okay.